# Java, what is best way to compare two lists?

Tags: android, list, comparison

I have two lists of Default and Chrome browsers history.
I want to merge these two lists into one list.
I need to update item if I find it duplicate (is common between two lists).

So, my "BrowserRecord" class is like this:

```
public class BrowserRecord {

private long id;
    private int bookmark;
    private long created;
    private long date;
    private String title;
    private String url;
    private long visits;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        BrowserRecord record = (BrowserRecord) o;
        return url.equals(record.url);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return url.hashCode();
    }

// other getter setter methods
...
}
```

and finally, I have a method that gets browsers histories and does merging:

```
public List<BrowserRecord> getHistory() {
        List<BrowserRecord> browserList = new ArrayList<BrowserRecord>();

        // get history of default and chrome browsers
        List<BrowserRecord> defaultList = getDefaultBrowserHistory();
        List<BrowserRecord> chromeList = getChromeBrowserHistory();

        Log.e(TAG, "=> size of Default browser:" + defaultList.size());
        Log.e(TAG, "=> size of Chrome browser:" + chromeList.size());

        // compare list A with B, update A item if equal item found in B and push it to tempList
        for(int i=0; i<chromeList.size(); i++) {
            BrowserRecord chromeBrowser = chromeList.get(i);

            for(int j=0; j<defaultList.size(); j++) {
                BrowserRecord defaultBrowser = defaultList.get(j);

                if(chromeBrowser.equals(defaultBrowser)) {
                    if(chromeBrowser.getBookmark() != defaultBrowser.getBookmark())
                        chromeBrowser.setBookmark(1);

                    chromeBrowser.setVisits(chromeBrowser.getVisits() + defaultBrowser.getVisits());
                }
            }

            browserList.add(chromeBrowser);
        }

        // compare list B with A, jump if equal item found in A, push to tempList if item not found
        for(int i=0; i<defaultList.size(); i++) {
            BrowserRecord defaultBrowser = defaultList.get(i);
            boolean found = false;

            for(int j=0; j<chromeList.size(); j++) {
                BrowserRecord chromeBrowser = chromeList.get(j);

                if(defaultBrowser.equals(chromeBrowser)) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(!found)
                browserList.add(defaultBrowser);
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "=> size of final browser:" + browserList.size());
        return browserList;
    }
```

I have tested this method and is working fine. Since my history records on mobile device after 3 years didn't exceed more than 200 records on one list and 150 for others, I assume something similar is happening for other users. But I'm sure is not optimum way.

What do you recommend?
any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand correctly, but it seems like what you're trying to do is, given both lists, create a final list which will contain all of the elements from both lists, removing any duplicates.

If this is the case, then take a look at Java's [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) class. If you iterate over all of the elements from both your lists and insert them into a `TreeSet`, you will basically get the result you're looking for. You can then use an `Iterator` to create an `ArrayList` containing all of the non-duplicate items from both your lists. As a side-effect of using a TreeSet, they will ordered (you can also use either a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) if you don't care about the order or a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) if you want to preserve the order of insertion).